# How to assign a value to a None Option when we use as_mut()?

Tags: rust, option-type

For example, if we have the following struct:

```rust
struct A {
    value: Option<i32>,
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { value: Some(1) };
    // want to update a's value
    match a.value.as_mut() {
        Some(v) => *v += 1,
        None => {},
    }
}
```

then we can modify the struct `A`'s `value` field using `as_mut()`. But if `a`'s `value` field is `None`, how can we assign a new value? For example:

```rust
struct A {
    value: Option<i32>,
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { value: None };
    // want to update a's value
    match a.value.as_mut() {
        Some(v) => *v += 1,
        None => {???},
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: consider https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as:

```rust
match a.value.as_mut() {
    Some(v) => *v += 1,
    None => a.value = Some(1),
}
```

But I guess you want to somehow assign from the binding of `as_mut()`, and this is impossible.

`as_mut()` converts `&mut Option<T>` to `Option<&mut T>`. While in the original form, `&mut Option<T>`, we can assign to the `None` (because it is still behind the reference), with `Option<&mut T>` the `None` is freestanding. It is not a reference, it is just a value, like another variable, without any correlation to the original variable.

Fortunately, you can pattern-match against the original `&mut Option<T>` too, and thanks to match ergonomics this looks completely the same:

```rust
match &mut a.value {
    Some(v) => *v += 1,
    v @ None => *v = Some(1),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
None => { a.value = Some(10); // Assign a new value, for example 10 }
```